# Tiddlywiki5 Howto use fields in HTML Code

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I'm trying to use tiddlywiki to build a store of parts I ordered online. Each tiddly represents one part and has several fields, such as price or order-number...
How can I use Tiddlywiki fields within the Tiddlywiki markup or HTML, eg. how can I make this to work:

```html
<a href="distributor.org/search?q={{!!order-number}}">View Online</a>
```

I would like that Tiddlywiki replaces `{{!!order-number}}` by the value of the field order-number. But unfortunatly, `{{!!order-number}}` is not rendered.

Note that in the following snippet, it works partially:

```html
<a href="distributor.org/search?q={{!!order-number}}">View Online {{!!order-number}}</a>
```

Specifiyng the field between the a-tag (not in href) is render correctly, showing the value of the field `{{!!order-number}}`.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a working solution myself, which works for TW 5.1.13:

```html
\define build-link()
<a href="distributor.org/search?q=$(orderNumber)$">distributor</a>
\end

<$set name=orderNumber value={{!!order-number}}>
<<build-link>>
</$set>
```

1. Define the desired field, in this example `order-number`
2. Define a macro that includes a variable, eg. the macro `build-link` which uses the variable `orderNumber`. Note that the macro must be at the beginning of the tiddle.
3. Set a variable with the name as defined above.
4. Call the macro within the varible set environment.

This also works with Wikitext markup:

```html
\define build-link-mu()
[ext[distributor|distributor.org/search?q=$(orderNumber)$"]]
\end

<$set name=orderNumber value={{!!order-number}}>
<<build-link-mu>>
</$set>
```